# Putting form result in my database

Tags: php, database, mysql, forms, wpdb

i have a problem with my wordpress rn.
I did a form in html and js, and i want to put the actual result in my database where i created a table for it.

So basically i did a plugin in simple php that take the answers and just put them in my data base such as :

```
// Créer un tableau vide pour stocker les réponses nettoyées
        $reponse = array();
        
        // Parcourir le tableau $_POST et nettoyer chaque valeur
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                $reponse[$key] = sanitize_text_field($value);
            }
        }

        // Insérer les données en utilisant $wpdb->insert
        $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $reponse);


// Vérifier le résultat
 if ($result === false) {
        echo "Erreur lors de l'insertion des données : " . $wpdb->last_error;
echo $wpdb->show_errors;
echo $wpdb->last_query;
    } else {
        echo "L'insertion des données a réussi";
    }
```

But for some reason, when i use the form to test it, i ran into unknown problems. This code hit me with : `Erreur lors de l'insertion des données : Unknown column 'Classe' in 'field list.` Which is strange cause the actual column exist. There is no doubt to it. So i tweak the code to not insert this specific column, and suddenly i get the same error on another column. Like the code is just deciding that some column that exist in the table, doesn't exist.

Then I deleted almost every single column excepted `firstName` and `lastName`. Just to see. And suddenly the code works, but nothing is added to the database. So I don't get it.

Either it doesn't work and say my column doesn't not exist, or, it work but it doesn't add anything to the database.

```
Edit : Table +>
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Nom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Prenom VARCHAR(255),
Adresse VARCHAR(255),
`Code_Postale` VARCHAR(5),
Naissance DATE,
Telephone VARCHAR(10),
Mail VARCHAR(255),
`Probleme_de_sante` VARCHAR(255),
handicap ENUM('Non', 'Oui'),
RQTH ENUM('RQTH-Valides', 'RQTH-En-Attente', 'Pas-de-RQTH'),
`AucuneAide` VARCHAR(255),
`Aide_Technique` VARCHAR(255),
`Aide_Humaine` VARCHAR(255),
`Autre_aide` VARCHAR(255),
`Nom_Contact_Urgence` VARCHAR(255),
`Prenom_Contact_Urgence` VARCHAR(255),
`Relation_Contact_Urgence` VARCHAR(255),
`Numero_Contact_Urgence` VARCHAR(10),
Classe ENUM('Premiere_Annee', 'Deuxieme_Annee', 'Troisieme_Annee', 'Senpai'),
Paiement ENUM('Paiement_Annuel', 'Paiement_Trimestre', 'Paiement_Seance'),
reglement ENUM('espece', 'virement', 'cheque'),
dateEncaissement ENUM('5', '15', '25'),
Rythme ENUM('Hebdomadaire', 'Mensuel'),
Creneaux VARCHAR(255)
```

Comment: Piping everything in `$_POST` is a security hazard, I do not see the form or the JS that triggers the AJAX, or a table schema in your question though, can you edit those in?

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm sorry i didn't saw your reply, i'm pretty new here.

I put my table schema, thought i'm not really sure it's what you wanted ?
I don't have a trigger in my JS, i actually have a plugin in php that does what i put on previously.

And the form is long since it's a conditionnal form i don't think i could put it entirely here. Can i do something to help more ?
Basically everything work till "AucuneAide". From Then it doesnt work and idk why. I tried to remove it then i got a problem in "Nom_Contact_Urgence"...
Only the first part of the table seems to work